# Drupal - block deleted - how to retrieve

Tags: blocks

I just posted this to StackOverflow, but then I noticed this group, so apologies if this is a duplicated question.

We're running version 6.14 of Drupal (old, I know). On of our users recently deleted a block by accident in a series of rotating images. (Administer > site building > block). So now the block shows up as a blank, or "n/a".

She did manage to add another block in its place, but apparently that doesn't help - the n/a still displays. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: that depends entirely on the set up of that block - presumably it was a module, perhaps a views slideshow that created it?. The easiest solution is restore a backup. failing that, you need to figure out what the block actually did, in detail in order to try to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. There was a php module behind it, which another develeoper had previously mentioned. It's in a "themes" sub-directory for the home page.  I have no idea how to trace from the Drupal front end to the PHP module, however.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the new block the user created had a block number of "8", whereas the original block that was deleted had a number of "2". The fix was to go into custom themes for the homepage, edit page.tpl.php, and change the "module_invoke" to refer to the correct block